# Is it okay to inject a default HttpClient from .NET Core's IHttpClientFactory into GraphServiceClient's constructor for HttpClient reuse?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm using the `Microsoft.Graph` SDK in my ASP.NET Core project, and want to take advantage of .NET Core's `HttpClient` management via `IHttpClientFactory`.

I see that `GraphServiceClient` accepts a `HttpClient` parameter in its constructor, allowing me to pass in an injected `HttpClient` directly. It seems to be working fine.

But I did notice the constructor's documentation says:

> The System.Net.Http.HttpClient to use for making requests to Microsoft Graph.
> Use the Microsoft.Graph.GraphClientFactory to get a pre-configured HttpClient
> that is optimized for use with the Microsoft Graph service API

The typed `HttpClient` instance I'm injecting in is the default one created by .NET Core's `IHttpClientFactory`. Does it need some extra configuration to be "optimized" for use with the Graph SDK?

Comment: If your code can work,I think is ok.[GraphClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.graph.graphclientfactory?view=graph-core-dotnet),GraphClientFactory is used to create the HTTP client.And you said `The typed HttpClient instance I'm injecting in is the default one created by .NET Core's IHttpClientFactory.`So If your code can work,you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpClient` created by `GraphClientFactory` has `BaseAddress` set to

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/
```

With the following `DefaultRequestHeaders`

```
SdkVersion: xxx
FeatureFlag: xxx
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
```

`MaxResponseContentBufferSize` is set to `2147483647` and `Timeout` is set to `00:01:40`.

It should not be complicated to set up `HttpClient` for Graph API manually.